# Masstransit not creating exchange

Tags: c#, masstransit

Good day
I'm solving the problem that exchange is not being automatically created

I have registered Masstransit in net6 net core application using such uri opions (have tried both):

```
rabbitmq://myurl
rabbitmq://myurl:5672
```

Registration looks like this:

```
services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
            {
                mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(new Uri(
                        RabbitMqOptions.RabbitMqUri),
                        RabbitMqOptions.VHost,
                        credentials =>
                        {
                            credentials.Username(RabbitMqOptions.UserName);
                            credentials.Password(RabbitMqOptions.Password);
                        });

                    cfg.AutoStart = true;

                    cfg.Publish<IServerNotificationMessage>(e => e.ExchangeType = RabbitMQ.Client.ExchangeType.Direct);
                });
            });
            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Debugging publishing code shows that actual port used is 0 and bus control is null and not started
[see the print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V9JH.png)

How can I make the bus start? (as I understand cfg.Host returns void, rather than buscontrol, so that it cannot be explicitly started, have specified autostart option, though its still down)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

A URI is not required to configure MassTransit, you might just simplify your configuration as shown below.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
{
    mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(RabbitMqOptions.Host,
            RabbitMqOptions.Port,
            RabbitMqOptions.VHost,
            h =>
            {
                h.Username(RabbitMqOptions.UserName);
                h.Password(RabbitMqOptions.Password);
            });

        cfg.AutoStart = true;
        cfg.Publish<IServerNotificationMessage>(e => e.ExchangeType = RabbitMQ.Client.ExchangeType.Direct);
    });
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

The logs should show the bus starting, if they don't, then the hosted service is not being started. Is this an ASP.NET project, or a project using the .NET Generic Host?

Comment: it's an ASP.NET project

Comment: how can i check logs? you mean output?